# Motivation for Quasicategories

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

Recall that a simplicial set $X$ is called a **quasicategory** if for every $0<k<n$, every map $\Lambda^n_k\to X$ admits an extension to a map $\Delta^n\to X$. It is good to have a concise definition, but the definition of quasicategories is perhaps too concise and I don't understand the motivation behind it. There are three things I want to clarify:

1. People say that quasicategories model $(\infty,1)$-categories; $n$-simplices are like $n$-morphisms, so that an $(n+1)$-simplex serves as a morphism between $n$-simplices. But apparently, an $(n+1)$-simplex has $n+2$ faces, so it doesn't make sense for an $(n+1)$-simplex to be a homotopy between $n$-morphisms. How can I interpret an $(n+1)$-simplex as a "morphism between $n$-morphisms"?
2. If $n$-simplices correspond to $n$-morphisms, then what does it mean for an $n$-simplex to be invertible? Why does the horn-filling condition guarantee that every $n$-morphism, where $n>1$, is invertible?
3. Why do we omit $k=0$ and $k=n$ from the horn-filling condition? What's the difference between the inner horns and the outer horns? (I understand that the unique extension property for the inner horns characterizes nerves of small categories, but nerves of small categories also have extension properties for the inclusions $\Lambda_0^n\subset \Delta^n$ and $\Lambda^n_n\subset \Delta^n$as soon as $n\geq 4$, so why not require them for quasicategories?)

Can someone give an answer to the above questions? Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: All of your questions are answered in any textbook introducing the topic. What article are you reading that omits all these points?

Comment: @Zhen Lin I'm reading Cisinski's Higher Categories and Homotopical Algebra. Can you indicate specific references that answer the questions?

Comment: I am rather new to the $\infty$-world, so Id shy away from writing an answer, but maybe this helps: I don’t think of $n$-simplices as $n$-morphisms, but as fully coherent homotopies witnessing $n$-fold composition of 1-morphisms. If you go the $n$-morphism route intuitionwise, you kinda end up with globular sets (cells between cells between cells…), which doesn’t explain simplices at all. But if you wonder how to express $n$-fold composition *up to homotopy* in a quite efficient manner, simplicial sets arise quite naturally

Comment: @Ken It seems I was mistaken. Perhaps you should consider reading chapter 1 of Lurie's _Higher topos theory_, which has somewhat more detail.

Comment: Next to Lurie's HTT chapter 1 (which is great for intuition) there are also a number of expository articles that you can find on the internet which explain the intuition of this stuff.

Comment: @Jonas Linssen Your insight definitely helps. So maybe I shouldn't think of quasicategories as $(\infty, 1)$-categories (whatever they are) (even if they do), but rather as a mathematical gadget which expresses homotopy-coherent associativities in a compact manner. (Although it is undeniable that the two notions are almost like cousins.) Thanks!

Comment: @Zhen Lin Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @QiZhu Thank you for your comment. Although Lurie's HTT Chapter 1 answered my questions, it never hurts to read someone else's account. Do you have any favorite?

Comment: Not in particular, they are all good. :-)

Comment: @Ken It's important to note that quasicategories really do model $(\infty,1)$-categories, in the sense that there are Quillen equivalences between them and any other kind of thing that you could possibly want to call an $(\infty,1)$-category (see barwick and schommer-pries: https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0040). So you should think of quasicategories *simultaneously* as $(\infty,1)$-categories and as structures encoding homotopy coherent $n$-fold compositions of morphisms (which you might more naturally call $A_\infty$-categories.)

Comment: I just learned a relevant fact that if $X$ is a quasicategory and $x,y$ its objects, the simplicial set $X(x,y)$ of maps from $x$ to $y$ is a Kan complex. This has an interpretation that $2$-morphisms are invertible. And one can repeat this procedure on and on to show that any $n$-morphisms are invertible for $n>1$.